# module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag' while deploying django application to AWS Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying my django application using elastic beanstalk's CLI and it is showing following errors in the logs.

I have created a python 2.7 environment, and have verified by typing "python -V" into the EC2 instance and it shows correct python version (2.7) but somehow in the error logs it seems that python3.6 is being used. Please have a look at the following error

```
Collecting enum==0.4.6 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 43))
    Downloading enum-0.4.6.tar.gz
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
          import distutils.core
        File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/distutils/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
          import imp
        File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/imp.py", line 27, in <module>
          import tokenize
        File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 33, in <module>
          import re
        File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
          class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
      AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
```

When I build locally, it works perfectly but it's happening only when I upload my code to elastic beanstalk using "eb deploy" command.

Comment: It states `python3.6`, so maybe pip, or setuptools are switched to 3.6?

Comment: Do you know any way how to switch them to use the 2.7 version?

Comment: Not really... There are two points that should have 2.7 - `virtualenv`, `eb create`. According to your post - all is done OK. Maybe you can go to `/var/log` and look around? Like `grep -r python .` there

Comment: You were able to solve the issue? I'm getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

The enum package has known issues with newer versions of Python and Django. 
You have enum in your requirements. Is your local server running ok? Does check go through?

```
python ./manage.py check
```

I'd suggest getting rid of enum. If it is preinstalled on your instance, remove the package with:

```
sudo rm -r /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/enum
```

Related, close to duplicate Q: [enum34 issue in Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47413574/enum34-issue-in-elastic-beanstalk)

Comment: This worked for me because I couldn't even used pip to uninstall the module do that error.